# How can I add a blurred gradient behind an image?

Tags: html, css

What would the html and css look like to create a blurred gradient underneath an image?
I understand how to create the gradient, but am not sure how to get it underneath images.

Something like this:

[image]

The gradient can be found here:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(98,52,255,1) #6234FF%, rgba(255,0,128,1) 100%);
```

Comment: is box-shadow property what you looking for?

Comment: is it possible to do a gradient box-shadow?

Comment: You can use gradient background on a box shadow like in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a `custom-gradient` class which is styled like that:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom-gradient {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px 12px white, inset 0 0 3px 2px white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(98, 52, 255, 1), #6234FF, rgba(255, 0, 128, 1))
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-gradient">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <h1>My image</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```